# Create a custom UserControl using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I Created a custom `UserControl` using Windows Form Control Library.And I want to create a property of `UserControl`which I can add item to it, then I can select item like comboBox.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are trying to do? What does the image have to do with creating a property? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: I mean I want to create a property like `Locked Property`,so I can select item in combobox

Comment: why creating a usercontrol when you have combobox?

Comment: What you ask are called _[UI Type Editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinForms allows you to create a rich design-time environment as well as providing for customised editors at runtime for certain properties that you define.

For example, if I plonk a `MessageQueue` component onto my WinForms form and view the **Properties** window, I can see a property named **Formatter**.

[image]

Clicking on the **Formatter** property however displays a drop-down box showing a preset list of values.  This is an example of a **UI Type Editor**.

[image]

One way to do this is to define an enum for your supported values (it could be a dynamic list if you wish).

```
public enum Muppets
{
    Kermit,
    MissPiggy,
    Fozzie
}
```

...then after defining your own editor derived from `UITypeEditor` (see MSDN link below)

```
class MyMuppetEditor : UITypeEditor { ... }
```

...you attach it to your control's property that you wish to have a drop-down as so:

```
[Category("Marquee")]
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorAttribute(typeof(MyMuppetEditor),
                 typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public Muppets Muppet {get ; set; }
```

For more detailed information check out the link below.

### More

- *[Walkthrough: Implementing a UI Type Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*
- *[Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)*

**EDIT:** To allow for dynamic list, try making the property a string because that's what the selection will be bound to and during `EditValue()` when showing your SelectionControl just display a listbox of your dynamic items

Comment: What I do to add more item to enum by code in designer?

Comment: You define the enum with all possible values in code, then through action of the `UITypeEditor`, the values will appear automatically in the designer at runtime.  Check out the Walkthrough for a guide.

Comment: I know but the number of value is not fixed, they can be changed

Comment: Try making the property a `string` because that's what the selection will be bound to and during `EditValue()` when showing your `SelectionControl` just display a listbox of your dynamic items

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the CategoryAttribute class.

Example:

```
[Description("Description of property here"), Category("Design")] 
public bool my_property;
```

Check out the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) page for a more complete reference on how to use it.

EDIT: In the case of wanting to have a bool property, use this example.

```
private bool my_bool = true; // this is its default value

[PropertyTab("Property Tab Name")]
[Browsable(true)]
[Description("Description of Property"), Category("Data")]
public bool my_property
{
    get { return my_bool; }
    set { my_bool = value; }
}
```

Comment: I mean I want to create a property like combobox to select item

Comment: Jake, that is not my issue. I want to create a property of UserControl which I can add item to it, then I can select item like comboBox.

Comment: @TuanNguyen So you don't want it to be a bool, and instead you want it to be customised text?

Comment: Jake,Can you help me please?

Comment: @AJHope What you ask are called _[UI Type Editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_

Comment: @AJHope See new answer

Answer (score 0):

I removed my last answer because I misunderstood your point.

An **easy** solution would require to make a `Collection` of  `enum` as a property. The Designer property grid will automatically give you the choice among your initialized `Collection` with a ComboBox. The displayed names will also be the `enum`'s name.

E.g. (something I made for a TextBox that only allows a certain type of value)

The `enum` :

```
enum EnumSupportedType
{
    Integer = 1,
    Double
}
```

The class where the property is located :

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBoxBase, INumericControl
{
    private EnumSupportedType _supportedType = EnumSupportedType.Integer;
    public EnumSupportedType SupportedType {
        get { return _supportedType; }
        set { _supportedType = value; }
    }
}
```

Then these items are suggested in a ComboBox (in the Designer property grid) :

- Integer
- Double

---

If you can't use enumerations, you can refer to [Providing a Custom UI for Your Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) which seems to be a much harder solution to implement but will solve your problem.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: `enum` is a static array, what I do to add more item to it by code?